# Python attrs with Random Attribute Value?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-attrs

I am using [`attrs`](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/) to create the class `A` with attribute `surprise` then should return a different random value (maybe choosen from a list of possible values) everytime it is accessed.

```py
@attr.s
class A(object):
   surprise = attr.ib(type=str)
```

How can we add a hook to the accessing of the `surprise` attribute of the class? This hook can allow us to generate a new string value on each access of the `surprise` attribute.

Thanks!

**Desired:**

```
a = A()
print a.surprise   # foo
print a.surprise   # bar
print a.surprise   # another_random_str
```

Comment: can't you just use `@property` decorator to return a new value for `surprise` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
from random import randint
class A:
    my_vars = ["str1", "str2", 1, 2, "whatever"]
    @property
    def surprise(self):
        return self.my_vars[randint(0, len(self.my_vars)-1)]
```